# Cannot install a spring-boot fat jar to a maven repository using gradle

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I wrote a spring-boot application with gradle and it runs properly.

I build a fat jar using bootRepackage, I added the maven plugin so I can install the jars.

The problem is that I can't install the fat jar to the maven repository.

1. "bootRepackage" builds that fat jar file
2. install is dependent on the "jar" phase so it builds a thin jar overriding the fat jar file
3. The thin jar is copied to the repository

Here's my gradle script for the base project, note that I'm still trying to install to my local repository (we're a new company and we're still building a remote repository)

```
subprojects {
group 'myGroup'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.6.RELEASE'
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE'
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.0'

    }

}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}



dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.4'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7'
}



task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.12'
}
}
```

Gradle script for the module:

```
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: "spring-boot"

repositories {
jcenter()
}

dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:2.0.3.RELEASE'
}
}
dependencies {
   compile "org.springframework:spring-web"
   compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
   compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
   compile 'com.netflix.feign:feign-okhttp:8.16.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ensure that the `bootRepackage` task runs before `install`. A crude way to do that is to specify both on the command line:

```
./gradlew bootRepackage install
```

A better approach is to configure the `install` task to depend on the `bootRepackage` task. You can do so by adding the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
install {
    dependsOn bootRepackage
}
```

With this configuration in place, Gradle will automatically run `bootRepackage` when you run `install`. For example:

```
$ ./gradlew install
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:install

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.487 secs
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it on Sunday

Comment: It worked but the syntax was a bit different: install.dependsOn {
        bootRepackage
    }